# Дружественный оператор ">>" для своего класса

Tags: c++

Есть условный класс A:

```
// A.h
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    A() = default;

    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, A &el);
}

// A.cpp
istream &operator>>(istream &in, A &el)
{
    //el.a = 3; - не видит поле a, класса A
}
```

В определении дружественной ф-ции, я пытаюсь считать из потока информацию в класс A, но почему-то нет доступа к приватной части объекта, хотя ф-ция дружественная. Я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Ваш реальный код, очевидно, отличается. Приводите код, на котором проблема воспроизводится.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не верно обращаетесь к полю! Нужно

```
el.a = 3;
```

a не

```
A.a = 3;
```

`A` - имя класса, а `el` - ссылка на объект.

Comment: Всё, всё я исправил, глупая ошибка в составлении примера

Comment: @ВикторСадовин бывает. Так а теперь работает?

Comment: В коде то у меня ошибки нету, той которую я допустил в примере. Там ничего не изменилось, всё ещё не видит приватное поле

Comment: @ВикторСадовин значит пример не полный, продемонстрируйте весь ваш код ф-ции.

Comment: https://github.com/sadovin-viktor/ps-oop/blob/c1b5a27146098ba6c519c80a7dccff56d271cf1b/Lab5/1.%20Rational/Rational.cpp#L195 - ссылка на гитхаб, конкретный пример

Comment: у вас ошибка в заголовочном файле: вы забыли написать `std::` при перегрузке операторов

Comment: ну а в остольном ошибок не заметил. должно работать

Comment: Ах да, аргументы ф-ции, благодарю!

Comment: @Виктор Садовин: Код на GitHub тоже не содержит ошибок про "доступ к приватной части объекта". Откуда взялся вопрос про "нет доступа к приватной части объекта"?

Answer (score 1):

```
istream& A::operator>>(istream &in, A &el)
{
    //...
}
```

вы забыли указать что это оператор класса А
Тут я был не прав. Оставлю, чтоб комментарии  не оказались воздухом. 
У вас только ошибка компиляции. В конце определения класса отсутствует точка с запятой...

Comment: Это не оператор класса...

Comment: Это оператор `istream`

Comment: да, я  грубо ошибся